# Saving high resolution plot in png

Tags: r, heatmap

I try to save heatmap in png.

```
png(paste(colnames(pt2)[jj], "_heatmap.png", sep=""), width = 465, height = 225, res = 300)
heatmap.2(S5, Rowv=F,Colv=F, scale="none", trace="none", col=rg, mar=c(3.5,0,3,0),
      dendrogram = "none", key=TRUE, keysize=0.2, key.par=list(cex=0.1),
      xlab="hour of the day", ylab = "day of the week",
      density.info = "none", lmat=rbind(c(5, 4, 2), c(6, 1, 3)), 
      lhei=c(3, 4.5), lwid=c(0.1, 5, 1),
      cexRow=1, cexCol=1, margins = c(3,0))
dev.off()
```

But it works only with res=100 maximum. I also tried to save it into file with 10X height and width, such as width = 4650, height = 2250. But then i can't change size of the font for the key, it's too little and unseen. How can I solve with high resolution? It shows

```
Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
Error in par(op) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pin"
```

Comment: Not the solution to the problem directly, but perhaps it's possible to produce the heatmap with `ggplot2` as can be seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732412/heat-maps-in-r-with-heatmap-2

Answer (score 8):

Your picture size is too small to fit the margins.  Note that the default units for `png` are pixels.  Thus, your height of 225 px, at a resolution of 300 dpi, gives an image that is less than one inch high

As a minimal example, this works (when we specify units as millimeters):

```
png("heatmap.png", width = 465, height = 225, units='mm', res = 300)
  plot(1:10, 1:10, mar=c(3.5,0,3,0))
dev.off()
```

whereas, this (with units in pixels) throws the same error as you had

```
png("heatmap.png", width = 465, height = 225, res = 300)
  plot(1:10, 1:10, mar=c(3.5,0,3,0))
dev.off()
```